# wp_create_user not properly entering password

Tags: wpdb, wp-create-user

I'm trying to create a new user after someone fills out a form. I'm using `wp_create_user` to do so. A user is being created properly, but, for whatever reason, no password is being submitted to the `users` table. It's simply a blank value.

First of all, I should note that, unfortunately, for this project I'm on 3.1.3 and there is very little chance that I'd be able to use 3.2.1.

I've checked to make sure that the password is correct up to the point that it is passed to the `wp_create_user` function and the value is as expected. I've also gone so far as to trace the password to the `wp_insert_user` function. It passes through the `wp_hash_password` function and comes out as a 34 character password hash. I then checked to see what the value of the password is before the `$wpdb->insert` method is executed to insert the user. The password is still the beautiful hash, not an empty value. I then kept on down the rabbit whole into the `_insert_replace_helper` method of the `$wpdb` class. The data fed to that function was just fine; however, the function returns:

```
return $this->query( $this->prepare( $sql, $data ) );
```

I went to look at the `prepare` method and it is defined as:

```
function prepare( $query = null ) { // ( $query, *$args )
```

Yes that little comment is from the actual code. When I saw it, I thought the previous dev had made this alteration. I was initially furious until I diffed it against the real file and found it to be identical. So, my confusion here is that the `_insert_replace_helper` method is calling the `prepare` method and sending it two arguments when it expects 1. What in the world is going on here?

Ultimately, I have two questions:

1) Why isn't my password being sent to the database
2) What is going on with the `_insert_replace_helper` method sending two arguments to the `prepare` method?

I should note that the function I'm using to add the user looks like:

```
// Function for registering user
function gov_register_user($name, $password, $email, $company, $phone)
{
    // If user is registered, don't register him/her again, but return true so no error is flagged
    if(email_exists($email))
        return true;

    // If any of the necessary fields are not filled, return false
    if($name == '' || $password == '' || $email == '')
        return false;

    // It's now safe to register the user
    $user_id = wp_create_user($name, $password, $email);
    if($user_id)
    {
        // Email user
        add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html"; '));
        wp_mail($email, 'Registration', get_mail_user_registration($name, $email));

        // Set meta fields
        set_cimyFieldValue($user_id, 'COMPANY', $company);
        set_cimyFieldValue($user_id, 'PHONE', $phone);

        // Log user in
        $gov_creds = array(
            'user_login' => $name,
            'user_password' => $password,
            'remember' => true
        );
        wp_signon($gov_creds, false);   

        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I found that this might have to do with the Cimy User Extra Fields plugin. It uses the `user_register` hook found at the end of the `wp_insert_user` function to manipulate some userdata. Interestingly they comment in the function "// avoid to save stuff if user is being added from: /wp-admin/user-new.php and shit WP 3.1 changed the value just to create new bugs :@". I think this might be part of my problem, but I'm still having a hard time working around it.

Comment: Fixed it...was a plugin issue with CIMY User Extra Fields. I'll give Rarst the accept for ruling out the WordPress issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP support [variable-lengths argument lists](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list). Simply put you can pass as many additional arguments as you want to any function and PHP won't even blink.

If you look at the [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.2/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L841) of [`$wpdb->prepare()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) method it simply fetches all arguments with [`func_get_args()`](http://www.php.net/func_get_args) into variable and works with that. It doesn't care about function signature (older or current either) at all.

So I think this is completely unrelated to your password issue, I'd try poking that plugin.

PS 3.2 is not that much different from 3.1, why problem upgrading? Running outdated version is trouble in the long run.

Comment: Thanks Rarst! I'll add the variable-lengths argument lists information to the "things that Rarst taught me" bin. Regarding 3.1, I'm just helping someone else fix a certain part of the site; not responsible for the rest. Would love to update, but there is guaranteed problems after update given the way its been put together.